# Django ModuleNotFoundError after creating models

Tags: python, django

I've started learning Django and struggling with creating/migrating a model.
Everytime I try to type *python manage.py migrate*(or anything), I get the error **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'People'**.

Here's my directory structure;

```
|- VLCase
    |- VLCase
        |- models.py 
        |- urls.py
        |- settings.py
        |- asgi.py
        |- __pycache__
        |- wsgi.py
    |- manage.py
    |- db.sqlite3
```

Here's my *models.py*;

```
from django.db import models

class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I added *People* into INSTALLED_APPS;

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'People',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

I couldn't find the answer. I would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would highly recommend you to follow the Django tutorial if you are starting out - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/. It covers all the concepts and gives you a good foundation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should write in your `INSTALLED_APPS` is the name of your application, so in your case it's `VLCase`, not `People`.

Your `People` class only refer to one of the models of your application and doesn't need to be added to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Ohh. It seems I didn't understand ```INSTALLED_APPS``` clearly. Thank you so much, it makes so much sense now.